# slider is not working in my web page

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

how to make a slider load faster?

```
       var jssor_1_options = {
          $AutoPlay: true,
          $SlideDuration:100,
          $SlideEasing: $Jease$.$OutQuint,
          $CaptionSliderOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorCaptionSlideo$,
            $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideoTransitions
          },
          $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
          },
          $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$
          }
        };

        var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can decrease or compress the image without affecting their quality on http://compressjpeg.com/